# Rails - number of rows in a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, csv, fastercsv

Hey. How can I get a total number of rows in a file (do not want to do it with loop). I'm reading CSV file.

Example 1

```
CSV.open('clients.csv', 'r')
```

Example 2

```
FasterCSV.foreach('clients.csv')
```

Thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How large is your file?

This option loads the entire file into memory, so if there are size/memory concerns it might not work.

```
numrows = FasterCSV.read('clients.csv').size
```

This option uses Ruby's built-in CSV module, which as you know is quite slow, but it does work. It also loads the entire file into memory:

```
numrows = CSV.readlines('clients.csv').size
```

Both *FasterCSV.read* and *CSV.readlines* return arrays of arrays, so you can use any array magic you want on the results.

Comment: Ruby 1.9 don't support FasterCSV

Comment: Then I suppose the other solution might be more useful in Ruby 1.9 - it's slow but it works :) Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @VP I think that's not quite right. Actually FasterCSV _is_ the csv in 1.9: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6090840/603309

Comment: @Roadmaster what if there is a large cvs file  (e.g 1GB) and we don't want to load it into memory?