# fastercsv error with ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, fastercsv

I have an existing rails application I'm running on ruby 1.9.2 and linux its rails version is

```
rails 2.3.8
```

and it has a GEMFILE as well, in its vendor/gems directory it has 'fastercsv-1.5.4' gem
and in its migrations (in two migrations) it has required the gem 'fastercsv'

```
require 'fastercsv'
```

But when I do

```
rake db:migrate
```

it fails the migration claiming

*"Please switch to Ruby 1.9's standard CSV library.  It's FasterCSV plus support for Ruby 1.9's m17n encoding engine."*

and I have found out the message comes from gems 'faster_csv.rb' file. as it has a condition  to check the ruby version

```
if RUBY_VERSION >= "1.9"

  class FasterCSV
    def self.const_missing(*_)
      raise NotImplementedError, "Please switch to Ruby 1.9's standard CSV "  +
                                 "library.  It's FasterCSV plus support for " +
                                 "Ruby 1.9's m17n encoding engine."
    end

    def self.method_missing(*_)
      const_missing
    end

    def method_missing(*_)
      self.class.const_missing
    end
  end

-- and more code
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this issue. Please note 'fastercsv' has not been added to the GEMFILE.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer to my question

Its based on this post

[What is Ruby 1.9 standard CSV library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011395/what-is-ruby-1-9-standard-csv-library)

and as the solution i had to

```
require 'csv'
```

instead of

```
require 'fastercsv'
```

and change the FasterCSV to CSV

Comment: Same here, otherwise you end up with an uninitialized constant Object::CSV (NameError)..

Comment: Oh i hope this works, cause i'm getting Object::CSV in my app and it's frusturating.  Will report back and high five this answer if it's right!

Answer (score 38):

You don't need to use the FasterCSV gem with Ruby 1.9.2 as it is already included as standard library's `CSV` (e.g. `require 'csv'`). Just change references in your application from `FasterCSV` to `CSV` and remove the `vendor/gems/fastercsv` folder and it should Just Work(tm)

Comment: I only had to remove `fastercsv` from my Gemfile and change references from `FasterCSV` to `CSV`.  I didn't have to delete any directories.  Otherwise, this answer Just Worked(tm) for me.

Comment: Also change the `require` statement from `'fastercsv'` to just `'csv'` per the accepted answer below.  At first I thought I could remove the require statement after reading this answer.